# CSS: можно ли не задавать цвет текста напрямую, а накладывать на уже существующий?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть таблица с валидными и невалидными полями, которые отличаются цветом текста, но если выделить какой-то элемент, то применяется новый стиль. Можно ли задать инверсию цвета существующего текста или что в этом роде?

Comment: нет, правило всегда будет целиком переопределять предыдущее. Однако вы можете играть с opacity, text-shadow/box-shadow и css-препроцессорами, которые позволят вам вычислять конечный цвет

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно.
http://jsfiddle.net/23e1j6b6/
Вот пример. Это называется порядки в CSS. Во втором input у меня совпадение по двум порядкам, а в первом, по одному. Поэтому для второго селектора применится второе правило, которое переопределит настройки из первого.

Answer (score 0):

Не силен в jq, но, может быть поможет эта статья - http://habrahabr.ru/post/149864/